# Is there any param field for page.route to add params to url in playwright

Tags: playwright

I am mocking my request in playwright with page.route

```
await page.route(
    ${API_URL}?id=9ffdbg94443rf0485ngdfjfa&source=admin,
    async (route) => {
      await route.fulfill({
        json: fixture,
        status: 200,
      });
    },
  );
```

Is there any param field for page.route like this to add params for that url

```
param:{
  id:"....",
  source:"..."
}
```

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: I do not want to add params manually to URL,  I am using the same route with different query params. I can build a helper function for that but Cypress intercept API has a "query" field for that functionality. I just wondering if the playwright has this or not.

Answer (score 0):

`page.route()` does not currently have a `param` field for the API URL. So you can use a helper function that dynamically creates url with params like this.

```
function buildUrl(baseUrl, params) {
  const url = new URL(baseUrl);
  Object.entries(params).forEach(([key, value]) =>
    url.searchParams.append(key, value),
  );
  return url.toString();
}

 await page.route(
    buildUrl(API_URL, params),
    async (route) => {
      await route.fulfill({
        json: fixture,
        status: 200,
      });
    },
  );
```